# if return data is null alert ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to show can alert message in the ajax return request if the return request does not contain any data !!!

i have tried in the ajax success but nothing is working!

This is my script ---

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchform").on('submit', function (e) {
            var data = {};
            data['contentSearch'] = $('#contentSearch').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/home',
                type: 'post',
                data: data,
                success: function (returnedData) {
                    $("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());
                   // how can i do something where so if the return value is null alert
                    }
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

console.log(returnedData) output
[image]

Do anyone knows how i can make an alert when the return value is null !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851337/check-if-ajax-response-data-is-empty-blank-null-undefined-0

Comment: Why not just check if (returnedData == null) { alert('a') } ??

Answer (score 4):

how about?

```
success: function (returnedData) {
                    if(!returnedData) alert('message');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but somehow it is not working for me

Comment: Do a console.log(returnedData); and post the answer

Comment: your response in not NULL. there is a javascript code in your response.and you should clear that

Comment: @now i have clear that and now in the console i get null

Comment: @h0mayan thanks for your answer, but something else is wrong i guess so evern when the return value is null it is not giving the laert message

Comment: post your current console.log(returnedData);

Answer (score 3):

Try this one....

```js
< script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#searchform").on('submit', function(e) {
          var data = {};
          data['contentSearch'] = $('#contentSearch').val();

          $.ajax({
              url: '/home',
              type: 'post',
              data: data,
              success: function(returnedData) {
               if(returnedData != "") {     $("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());
       } else {
       alert("Data is Null");
       }
              }
            }
          });

        return false;
      });
  }); < /script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function (returnedData) {
    if(!!returnedData && returnedData != null) {
        $("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());
    } else {
        alert('No data');
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
success: function (returnedData) {
    if(returnedData && returnedData.length) {
        $("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());
    } else {
        alert('No data');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but somehow it is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

```
success: function (returnedData) {
        $("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());
        // check whether your returned data is null
        if(returnedData == null)
        {
             alert("Your message");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it here --

```
success: function (returnedData) {
 if($.trim(returnedData.length))    
           $("#displayResult").html($(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html());
 else
           alert('Nothing got');

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you would like to do this:

```
success: function (returnedData) {
   var data = $(returnedData).find("#displayResult").html() || ""; // this won't alert but
   $("#displayResult").html(data); //                          sets a value if that's null
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do the same thingy. You can try the following code fragment. It checks your callback data`s length. Depends on it, you can trigger your success message etc. If the length of return data is zero which means NO DATA, you can trigger the message relevant to that scenario.

```
success: function (returnedData) {

    var sizeOfData = returnedData.length; // check the size of return data, be it zero means NO DATA

    if (sizeOfData != 0) {
        alert('Data exists !! Success !!');
    }
    else {
        alert('No Data !! Error !!');
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I see you've been on SO awhile. You answer is on a review queue because it was flagged as low-quality because there's no description. Please add a little text to explain the thing this answer solves. I'm not going to recommend deletion but someone else may opt to delete answers like this when reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below :

```
if (returnedData == 'null' || returnedData == null){
    alert('I am null');
}
```